# Correct position for heading tags

Tags: html

I was reading that the heading 1 tag should come before the opening body tag. Is that correct? I though the only thing that should come before the body tag was the DOCTYPE, opening html tag and head tags.

Comment: Where on Earth did you read that?  Yahoo answers? =D

Comment: I the SEO Bible. It wasn't necessarily saying that but it wasn't clear so I thought I ought to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading elements, including `<h1>` may appear only *inside* the `<body>` of an HTML document.

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) which says:

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where flow content is expected.

… and then links off to a description of flow content.

Comment: That's what I thoguht. The SEO Bible makes it unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Was it the `head` or `heading` tags? Both are two seperate tags that do seperate things.

A typical HTML structure should look like this:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

The `<head>` is where your includes such as JS files, CSS files, cdns, meta and page titles go.

The `heading` or `h1-6` are content types that belong in your body, which should be in order for 'most important for seo' (`h1`) to 'least important for seo' (`h6`). Also if you do not have a `CSS Reset`, they will be sized from largest(`h1`) to smallest(`h6`).